# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when trying to use cropper js

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cropperjs

I'm trying to use [cropper js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) to crop a image from [url](https://img.youtube.com/vi/nr8l_2G7G-g/maxresdefault.jpg)

but it is returning a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

```
var $img = $('<img/>');

$img.attr({src: src}).load(function () {
    $container.html($img);
    $container.css({maxWidth: 100});
    $container.css({maxHeight: 100});
    $img.cropper({
        cropBoxResizable: false,
        aspectRatio: 100 / 100,
        minCropBoxWidth: 100,
        minCropBoxHeight: 100,
        dragMode: 'move',
        fillColor: '#fff',
        crop: function (e) {
            $('.coords').val(e.x + ',' + e.y + ',' + e.width + ',' + e.height);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It probably relies on a `<canvas>`, and that mechanism won't allow code to "observe" an image from another domain.

Comment: you trie use:    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";     ?

Comment: @Pointy I'll try

Comment: @toto yes, and no success :(

Comment: I beelive that the problem is with the crop js that use canvas. I will send you and example soon.

Comment: some observation the line $container.html($img); change to $img.appendTo($container); this is  object not a html.

Comment: I tested it, the img load fine from remote src, the problem is that the croop plugin use canvas and tried convert the image to base64 using toDataURL and it failed for security reason crossdomain. 1 soluctions: create a php or aspx or jsp server page that download the image and resent the binary to image object. for image side is local image.

Comment: @toto is that what I was in mind

Comment: but I found this website https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/